# How to draw a cosine curve with complex numver in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How to draw a cosine curve with complex exponentials using gnuplot?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNFPb.jpg)

I tried to draw them using this script, but the graph is not drew.

```
set parametric
i = {0.0,1.0}
set size ratio -1
plot real(1/2*(exp(i*t)+exp(-i*t))), imag(1/2*(exp(i*t)+exp(-i*t)))
```

but I got nothing on the graph.

Example, circle in complex number

```
set parametric
i = {0.0,1.0}
set size ratio -1
plot real(1/2*(exp(i*t)+exp(-i*t))), imag(1/2*(exp(i*t)+exp(-i*t)))
```

Comment: What makes your expression have an imaginary component? I see, i is an imaginary number, I thought you were specifying a range.

Comment: I want to draw complex conjugate relations in Potential well in quantum physics with gnuplot.

when you plot such like blow, you got a circle in complex number.

plot real(exp(i*t)), imag(exp(i*t))

Comment: Did you try plotting `plot t, imag( 1/2*(exp(i*t) + exp(-i*t) ) )`? Did you try evaluating what exp(i*theta) + exp(-i*theta) equals? You're essentially trying to plot the imaginary component of an expression without an imaginary component.

Comment: when I plot
"plot real((exp(i*t)+exp(-i*t))), imag((exp(i*t)+exp(-i*t)))"
I got a plane horizontal line.
so it may be "exp(i*t) + exp(-i*t) = 0".

Comment: I showed the derivation in the answer. *The imaginary component is 0* so when you call imag( 1/2 *( ( exp(i*t) + exp(-i*t) ) ) you get zero. The real component is cos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the correct functions.

```
plot t, cos(t)
```

If you want to use exponentials

```
plot t, exp(i*t) + exp(-i*t)
```

You can see this with eulers equation.

```
exp(i*t) = cos(t) + isin(t)
```

Then the sum reduces to

```
exp(i*t) + exp(-i*t) = 2*cos(t)
```

No imaginary component.